# Elasticsearch / Posting and searching attachments

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get Elasticsearch to index a .txt file so that I can search the content. I've made some progress, but having no luck with the searching part.

Here is my mappings:

```
mappings: {
    file: {
        properties: {
            allow_token_share: {
                type: string
            },
            file: {
                type: string
            },
            deny_token_document: {
                type: string
            },
            _name: {
                type: string
            },
            _content_type: {
                type: string
            },
            type: {
                type: string
            },
            uri: {
                type: string
            },
            deny_token_share: {
                type: string
            },
            allow_token_document: {
                type: string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the document I got indexed:

```
{
    _index: f_drive,
    _type: file,
    _id: file:/C:/Users/ttobinca.EPIC/Documents/Dev/Epicsearch/TestDocs/Test.txt,
    _version: 1,
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        uri: C:\Users\ttobinca.EPIC\Documents\Dev\Epicsearch\TestDocs\Test.txt,
        allow_token_document: __nosecurity__,
        deny_token_document: __nosecurity__,
        allow_token_share: __nosecurity__,
        deny_token_share: __nosecurity__,
        type: attachment,
        _content_type: text/plain,
        _name: Test.txt,
        file: SSBsaWtlIGhhbWJ1cmdlcnMgYW5kIGhvdGRvZ3MsIGJ1dCBtb3N0bHkgY2hvY29sYXRlLg0KDQpIZWxsbyB3b3JsZC4=
    }
}
```

The content of the file is:

> I like hamburgers and hotdogs, but mostly chocolate.
>
> Hello world.

First question is, is this document indexed correctly?
And if so, how do I go about searching the content of this document? Running this query returns no results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "hamburgers"
    }
  }
}
```

But this returns the document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "SSBsaWtlIGhhbWJ1cmdlcnMgYW5kIGhvdGRvZ3MsIGJ1dCBtb3N0bHkgY2hvY29sYXRlLg0KDQpIZWxsbyB3b3JsZC4="
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just read the text out of the document and index that then search against it like a normal text field?

Answer (score 5):

Indexing of binary content is not supported by default. YOu have to install and use the [mapper-attachment plugin](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments). That will enable a custom `attachment` type that you can use in your mapping. That way elasticsearch will use apache tika to extract text from the binary and index it as text. Only after that you'll be able to get results with your text query.

Do take into account that using the attachment plugin you are executing the parsing of the binary content on the server side, within an elasticsearch node, which is probably not a great idea since you then would have to reserve power and memory on that node for that process instead of using it for indexing and searching text.

Comment: So, you mean to say that we can not index contents of a text file as String in Elastic search?

Comment: No. You can always index strings and text, the questions was about indexing binary content and indexing the context as text.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution - plugin at http://elasticwarehouse.org. You can upload binary file using _ewupload? then perform search via elasticwarehousestorage index using "filetext" or "filemeta" elements

Install plugin:

```
plugin -install elasticwarehouseplugin -u http://elasticwarehouse.org/elasticwarehouse/elasticsearch-elasticwarehouseplugin-1.2.2-1.7.0-with-dependencies.zip
```

Restart cluster, then:

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_ewupload?folder=/myfolder&filename=Test.txt" --data-binary @Test.txt
```

Sample response:

```
{"id":"nWvrczBcSEywHRBBBwfy2g","version":1,"created":true}
```

Search example:

```
curl -XGET "http://127.0.0.1:9200/elasticwarehousestorage/files/_search" -d '{
"query": {
    "term": {
       "filetext": {
          "value": "hamburgers"
       }
    }
}
}'
```

Comment: Did you get the answer for your question?